# Read values from case object field which is extending a trait using reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, enums

This might be a weird question, but I am trying something and stuck at this point.

For enumuerators, I am using the `sealed trait - case object` approach. I am trying to generate a Typescript class for each of the annotations to avoid mismatch between Frontend and Backend values for enums. Here is my sample enum implementation.

```
sealed trait BankingTypeEnum {
  val id: Long
  val name: String
}

object BankingTypeEnum {

  case object Cheque extends BankingTypeEnum {
    override val id: Long = 1
    override val name: String = "Loan"
  }

  case object Current extends BankingTypeEnum {
    override val id: Long = 2
    override val name: String = "Current"
  }

  case object Savings extends BankingTypeEnum {
    override val id: Long = 3
    override val name: String = "Savings"
  }

}
```

What I want to do is to get the values into a simple case class which can be later used to generating the typescript file. However, I am not sure how I can get the field values at generation time using reflection. If I use case class instead of case object, I can create an instance of the class using reflection, but I do not want to do that. Is there any other way, I can get the values, `id` and `name` fields of the case object enums ?

Comment: "What I want to do is to get the values into a simple case class which can be later used to generating the typescript file." What do you mean with generation time? Do you mean build or a you having a hook somewhere in between or do you execute a programm that will generate you a ts-file? It seems like you should basically use a Map.

Comment: @sascha10000 Yes, I have an sbt task which will generate the typescript files when executed. In that generator, I want to read all the enums(case object-sealed trait) and generate a Typescript file for corresponding enums.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution becaus you're kind of mocking scala Enumerations 
http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html

But regarding to your approach, you can just add a Set. Additionally I've put the trait into the object:

```
object BankingTypeEnum {
  sealed trait BankingType {
    val id: Long
    val name: String
  }

  val bankingTypes: Set[BankingType] = Set(Cheque, Current, Savings)

  case object Cheque extends BankingType{
    override val id = 1L
    override val name = "Loan"
  }
  case object Current extends BankingType{
    override val id = 2L
    override val name = "Current"
  }
  case object Savings extends BankingType{
    override val id = 3L
    override val name = "Savings"
  }
}
```

And then you may generate a const like:

```
BankingTypeEnum.bankingTypes.foldLeft("export const BankingTypes = {")((a,b) => {
  if(a != "export const BankingTypes = {")
    a + ",\""+b.name+"\":"+"{\"id\":"+b.id+",\"name\":\""+b.name+"\""+"}"
  else
  a + "\""+b.name+"\":"+"{\"id\":"+b.id+",\"name\":\""+b.name+"\""+"}"
}) + "}";
```

This will generate you:

```
export const BankingTypes = {"Loan":{"id":1,"name":"Loan"},"Current":{"id":2,"name":"Current"},"Savings":{"id":3,"name":"Savings"}}
```

The Set (you may use List or whatever) is just there that you won't need to use reflections....

Comment: The problem is I do not know what all are the enum types in my application, what I thought is I can extend all my enum with any other trait and use reflection to find out all the enums.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I thought you wanted to omit reflections. But if not (you can use your code from this post as it is):

```
val enums = for {
  f <- BankingTypeEnum.getClass.getDeclaredClasses
  c = f.getConstructors()(0)
  i = c.newInstance(BankingTypeEnum)
} yield (f.getMethod("id").invoke(i), f.getMethod("name").invoke(i))
```

And here is the according generating part (it produces the same as in my previous answer):

```
enums.foldLeft("export const BankingTypes = {")((a,b) => {
  if(a != "export const BankingTypes = {")
    a + ",\""+b._2+"\":"+"{\"id\":"+b._1+",\"name\":\""+b._2+"\""+"}"
  else
    a + "\""+b._2+"\":"+"{\"id\":"+b._1+",\"name\":\""+b._2+"\""+"}"
}) + "}";
```

What is happening? First one get the DeclaredClasses inside BankingTypeEnum. The next step is getting the constructors more concrete the first constructor (There is no "object" as offered in scala in the JVM). Now you create the instance from the constructor and return the id and name as tuple for each "case object" by invoking the methods.

You may search for articles about the scala byte code, because as stated before there are no "case classes" or "objects" in Java/JVM. They're constructed as classes and interfaces.
Same for the vals. For example

```
 val id:Long = 4L
```

will be (in Java-alike)

```
private long id = 4L; 
public long id() = { return this.id }
```

For that reason Iam invoking the methods name() and id() because the attributes name and id are private.